# why we use node.js and babel in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to reactjs,and installed the node.js and babel.I not have the clear idea for why we are using node.js and babel in react.Anyone know push me up in react..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are [multiple ways](https://github.com/facebook/react#installation) to start using React.js library. Although, the most convenient one is by using Babel+Webpack.

React uses [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) syntax. Babel is a transpiler i.e. it converts the JSX to vanilla JavaScript. You can view babel as an intermediate step between your code and "executable" code.

React also uses ES6, which is not supported by most of the browsers. Babel converts the ES6 code to a code which is compatible with the browsers.

The best combination for a mature React project would be React+babel+Webpack. In order to run babel and webpack, you'll need node.

I'd suggest you to take a tutorial first to get your hands dirty.

Comment: mihir i read the basic details about node.js but i still not get the clear idea about relationship  between node.js and react

Comment: Okay, no problem. There is no direct relation between React and Node. But React uses JSX and ES6 code which is not compatible with the browsers. So even if you write React components, they will not run in the browsers. That's why you'll need to convert that code to a code which can be understood by the browser. To convert that code, you will need babel. To run babel, you will need Node. You cannot run Babel without node. By implication, you will not be able to run React code.

Answer (score 4):

ReactJS uses its own language ([JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)), which is based on JavaScript but is not JavaScript.

Babel translates that syntax into JavaScript which can run in web browsers.

Babel depends on Node.JS to run.

Comment: fine quentin ... now i got idea about babel and plz give info about node.js look like your babel explanation.

Comment: @PraveenKumarInvoscape — "Babel depends on Node.JS to run"

Comment: I like to now the reasons for why babel depends node.js..plz give the details quentin

Comment: Because the authors of it decided to use Node.JS.